# Can't specify initialization method in Exponential smoothing

Tags: python, conda, statsmodels

When going through the exponential smoothing tutorial provided by [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/exponential_smoothing.html), I had an issue with specifying an initialization method in anaconda notebook. The error would return:

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initialization_method'

It would reference the first line in the cell:

fit1 = Holt(air, initialization_method="estimated").fit(smoothing_level=0.8, smoothing_trend=0.2, optimized=False)

When looking for the solution, I downgraded my prompt-toolkit but that didn't do anything. I can't find anyone else having this problem, any ideas?

Comment: What version of Statsmodels are you using? The `initialization_method` argument was added in Statsmodels v0.12.

Comment: I'm using 0.11.1. Might be the problem. But none of the keywords are working.

Comment: You need to upgrade to 0.12. The docs you link to are 0.12 and exponential smoothing has had a major overhaul between 0.11 and 0.12.